# HSQLDB: cannot drop column

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have an `hsqldb`, which contains `SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL MVLOCKS`.
I am trying to drop a column:

```
ALTER TABLE CSUSER DROP COLUMN PASSWORD
```

But i am having this error:

> Error: Error while executing action. Reason:
>   java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity
>   constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation;
>   SYS_PK_10426 table: CSUSER in statement [ALTER TABLE CSUSER DROP
>   COLUMN PASSWORD]

If i set `SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS`, I don't have an error and the column is dropped.

The problem is that i am forced to use `MVLOCKS`, and i am not finding any constraint on this column.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use set `SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS`, drop the column, then use
 `SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL MVLOCKS`.

The reason for the error is the existence of incomplete and uncommitted transactions. You need to commit all transactions.

So before performing a large-scale data and schema change operation, commit any transaction.

Comment: Thanks fredt, but this statement is executed during a migration started by the user, if i add a SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS before droping the column, the user will have this error:                                         java.sql.SQLException: invalid transaction state: active SQL-transaction in statement [SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS]

Comment: Perform all the migration after committing the transaction.